# How is "Splash damage" distributed?

Tags: clash-of-clans

How is splash damage distributed? Is it equally divided among units/buildings when dealt? Or is it set at a constant number and delivered that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a set amount of damage that's dealt to all targets within the splash radius. It's very important to make sure your units are not bunched up during an attack. A single mortar can destroy many lower level troops (Barbarian, Archer, ect) with one attack.

Comment: Note: the splash damage done my the lightning spell works differently.